# How can i hide my json requests from showing in firebug

Tags: json, security, request, firebug

how can i hide my json request URL from firebug console? 
It appears full as anyone can take it and retrieve our data to their website 
note i am talking to a third party and i can't do restricted calling domains on it

Comment: ?! stop sending json? if your browser is requesting it, firebug can see it. end of story

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you can't, and you must design your system so that you don't need to. You can try to obfuscate the request itself, but only if you control the protocol (which it sounds like you may not). But even then you're going to send all the javascript required to obfuscate the request to the browser, where it is available to be reverse engineered.

The final network traffic cannot be hidden from the user. It's their machine and their network. Even if you could stop Firebug somehow, the user can just use Charles. If you did find a way to stop Firebug, it would certainly be reported as a bug and fixed, so I wouldn't spend a lot of your development time on it.

If you need DRM, then you're going to need to investigate DRM (which has its own issues and is far from highly effective), but there's no practical way to do what you're discussing, and certainly not given your third-party restriction.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can hide your json if the browser requests it.